# Get .txt file from the available .pgp file(Data) and .asc file(Key)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gnupg, pgp

Using Python 2.17.12, Pycharm and Linux Ubuntu

Want to know how can I decrypt .pgp file to .txt file, using a key(.asc file) in Python Script.

Able to do it in python command line, but want to write a script for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import gnupg

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/path/to/directory')
```

**imported key**

```
key_to_import = '.asc key file'
key_data = open(key_to_import).read()
import_result = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
```

**decrypt File**

```
with open('.pgp file name', 'rb') as f:
    status = gpg.decrypt_file(f,passphrase='**appropriate_one**', output='.txt file name')
```

**check status**

```
print 'ok: ', status.ok
print 'status: ', status.status
print 'stderr: ', status.stderr
```

Worked for me, might help someone else.